# Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain when running the command: npx playwright install

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, chromium, playwright

I run

```
npx playwright install
```

in vs code terminal
and getting the next error:

```
Failed to install browsers
Error: Failed to download Chromium 102.0.5005.40 (playwright build v1005), caused by
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1532:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:946:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:727:12)
```

what can be the issue?
Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 0):

seems like your company is intercepting the traffic, so you need to set the custom certificate via env var

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected to any **VPN** like netskope or globalProtect,
please disconnect from it and then try ,

```
"npx playwright install"
```

Answer (score 0):

I work behind a netskope proxy. They way I got past the self signed cert in chain error is to set the NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS using a powershell command.

Open a powershell command window and enter the following being sure to update the file path to your cert

`$Env:NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS="C:\certs\root.crt"`

You can find more out here https://playwright.dev/python/docs/browsers